# Ubuntu 15.10: Suspend problem (Inspiron 7000)

Tags: suspend, hibernate, 15.10

I've just installed 15.10 on a new Dell Inspiron 13 7000 Series, after two catastrophic Hibernate crashes (needing OS reinstalls) on Trusty (14.04) over the last 3 days.

At this time, neither Suspend nor Hibernate work.

My /proc/acpi/wakeup has all entries disabled (except LID0, which is enabled).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

s1b.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved the suspend problem by getting into the BIOS at boot time (Setup) and disabling three USB-related settings.

It is likely that just one of the three is sufficient for Suspend to work, but I haven't tried to figure out which one.

s1b

Comment: can you specify in answer which are those usb settings?

Comment: btw, you dont need to sign (`s1b`) we can see your name on the bottom right :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem has returned yesterday (after several days of having no problems) after I installed a QT-based application.

The behaviour now is rather strange. While the 'Suspend' system menu item puts the laptop to sleep, it returns after a few seconds. However, if I close the lid, the laptop suspends correctly. The laptop does not automatically resume when the laptop lid is opened, and requires the power switch to be pressed for a few seconds.